# Using kbuild to build user space applications

Tags: kernel, compiling, application

I am referring to the following link:

[Linux Kernel Makefiles](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/kbuild/makefiles.html#loadable-module-goals-obj-m)

Under section **5 Userspace Program support**, explanation has been provided as to how to instruct kbuild to also build user space code. Based on this explanation, I tweaked the Makefile that originally built only the proprietary driver code, to build the test applications as well, as shown below (actual names have been replaced):

```
obj-m   += driver.o

KERNELVER       ?= $(shell uname -r)
KERNELDIR       ?= /lib/modules/$(KERNELVER)/build
PWD             := $(shell pwd)
always-y        := $(userprogs)
userprogs       := samples
samples-objs    := sample1.o sample2.o sample3.o sample4.o sample5.o sample6.o sample7.o

modules:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) clean
```

But this change does not build the `userprogs`; still only the driver code is built.

What am I missing here?

TIA

Comment: `:=` means "simply expand now". So `always-y` will be empty, as `$(userprogs)` has not yet been set. Try inverting the order.

Comment: @meuh I did try your suggestion but with no different result...

Comment: userprogs is a fairly recent addition, (perhaps June 2020?). Are you building a recent kernel? What target are you giving `make`?

Comment: @meuh I am building using kernel version 4.18.0-305.10.2.el8_4.x86_64. As shown in the above Makefile, the only two targets are "modules" and "clean". I am entering "make" from the command-line which should be the same as "make modules", after "clean".